# How to increase the timeout values for a WCF service in a dot net core 2.1 project

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am posting this because I was unable to find any place on Stack Overflow that addresses this issue for a .Net-Core project utilizing WCF by adding the service reference through Connected Services.

My issue was that I was facing client side timeouts because of long running operation requests.

So, how does one increase the timeout values for the wcf client objects since .Net-Core no longer uses the web config to store the configuration values for the WCF service references? (Please see my provided answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under Connected Services in Solution Explorer, after adding a  WCF service, a few files are generated for that service. You should see a folder with the name you gave the WCF service reference and under that a `Getting Started`, `ConnectedService.json` and a `Reference.cs` file.

To increase any of the client service object's timeout values, open `Reference.cs` and locate method: `GetBindingForEndpoint`

Inside this method you should see something like this:

```
if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IYourService))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                //Here's where you can set the timeout values
                result.SendTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                result.ReceiveTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

                return result;
            }
```

Just use `result.` and the timeout you want to increase like `SendTimeout`, `ReceiveTimeout`, etc. and set it to a new TimeSpan with the desired timeout value.

I hope this proves to be a useful post to someone.

Comment: Will this be overwritten if the service reference is updated or re-added?

Comment: @OchiFortune To be honest, I haven't had to update my service reference, so I am unsure of whether that will overwrite it or not. If you get a chance to test that, please feel free to add your findings.

Comment: Yes this will be replaced. Also never edit generated code...

Answer (score 12):

Answer by Ryan Wilson will work but only until you will try to update service. Reference.cs will be overwritten.
In .NET Core 3.1 you can grammatically modify binding timeouts:

```
 public MemoqTMServiceClass(string api_key)
    {
        
        client = new TMServiceClient();
        
        var eab = new EndpointAddressBuilder(client.Endpoint.Address);

        eab.Headers.Add(
              AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("ApiKey",  // Header Name
                                                 string.Empty,           // Namespace
                                                 api_key));  // Header Value

        client.Endpoint.Address = eab.ToEndpointAddress();
        client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
        client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
        client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just implement the following partial method in the generated proxy class to configure the service endpoint. Place the partial method in your own file to make sure it will not be overwritten.

```
static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can test out and configure timeouts in WCF more easily. The timeouts are configured in the client project.

First off, Image proof or it did not happen. Here you see that I get a timeout after already 15 seconds so how did I do that ?

[image: Quick timeout for WCF client]

Note, I use the following Nuget packages for the client, which is a .NET 6 console application:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The server project uses these Nuget packages, I have made  client and service WCF from the CoreWCF templates :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CoreWCF.Primitives" Version="1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreWCF.Http" Version="1.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Inside Reference.cs, the auto-generated file on the client we got this method:

```
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyService.IService>, MyService.IService
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

//more code
```

We make note of the namespace of the client and add the following partial class with a configured set of timeouts. Adjust as desired these timeouts.

I add a file called ServiceClient here, the class name matches the ServiceClient class name in the Reference.cs also.

```
namespace MyService
{
    public partial class ServiceClient
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
        {
            serviceEndpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout 
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        }

    }
}
```

Timeouts set here is set to 15 seconds. Obviously, you would like to have these timeouts perhaps a bit longer, I only entered a small value to quickly test it. Default values are usually either 30 or 60 seconds, in production you might consider many minutes in case your servicemethods should perform long running jobs - or consider a framework for this such as Hangfire instead.

The benefit of this approach is that if you update Reference.cs (which is still a bit cumbersome in VS 2022, not as easy as in ye ole days with WCF in .NET Framework), your configured settings are still kept. By setting the endpoint binding you can do a lot of other configuration too.

We can also avoid hardcoding timeouts by adding appsettings.json to our project and set the file to copy to output folder.

If you are inside a console project you can add json config file like this, preferably registering it in some shared setup in Program.cs, but I found it a bit challenging to consume it from a static method I ended up with this :

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_ =>
                    new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                        .Build())
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var config = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationRoot>();

            int timeoutInSeconds = int.Parse(config!["ServiceTimeoutInSeconds"]);
            serviceEndpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
        }
```

And we have our appsettings.json file

```
{
  "ServiceTimeoutInSeconds" :  9
}
```

The CoreWCF project got an upgrade tool that will do a lot of the migration for you. WCF had a lot of config settings and having an appsettings.json file for every setting will be some work. The upgrade tool should take care of generating some of these config values and add them into dedicated json files for this.