# The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00 Error, no app.config file on the project

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im getting this error when executing the following line:

The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout

`bool isUploaded = await provider.uploadSync(data, isRemote, token);`

there is no app.config file on the project, how can I increase timeout?

Comment: .NET Core an be provided configuration in a number of ways https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration

Comment: I do have appsettings.json, but I cant find how to increase timeout on that file, do you know where could I find that information?

Answer (score 3):

Added this lines on Reference.cs after

```
this.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
this.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
this.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
this.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

used this link to apply it [How to increase the timeout values for a WCF service in a dot net core 2.1 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046380/how-to-increase-the-timeout-values-for-a-wcf-service-in-a-dot-net-core-2-1-proje)